# Understanding the Domain object + Data mapper pattern?

Tags: php, oop

I've always worked with various ORM's in the past and placed all my logic inside my models regardless of it's nature - SQL, MongoDB queries & even fetching of remote JSON objects.
But when it's necessary to ensure loose couplings to allow a high level of testability, the issues of this methodology quickly appears.

Today I've read about separating models into two parts, `Domain objects` & `Data mappers`.
If I understood it completely, `Domain objects` are completely unaware of the storage used, and instead exists to handle business logic. `Data mappers` on the other hand takes care of storing the data set in the `Domain objects` to a set data storage.

I do however find it a bit hard to find a good, easy-to-understand example online on how to work with the DomainObjects & DataMappers in a real world example.

Would this (below shown code) be the appropriate way to work with DomainObjects & DataMappers in my code to store Users or have I gotten it all wrong in my head?

```
$user = new User_DO;
$userSave = new User_DM;
$userSave->store( $user->add(array('name' => 'John Doe')) );

class User_DO {

    function add($array) {
        if(!isset($array['name'])) {
            throw new Exception("Name must be set");
        }

        return $array;

    }

}

class User_DM {

    function store($array) {
        MyDatabase::execute("INSERT INTO...");
    }

}
```

Comment: a maybe stupid example in real world, but which can better explain the pattern, would be a domain object with an "age" field, while the data mapper persist the "year-of-birth" value.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The idea behind this is to have a standard object, that represents the current state in *real life* or in other words, in the domain. This *domain model* is usually a collection of data without logic.

```
class person_DO {
    public $id;
    public $firstname;
    public $lastname;
    public $addresses;
}
```

The loading of instances of this domain model (*domain objects*) and the persistence is handled through *data mappers* - e.g. the address of the above person might be located in another table via a 1:n relationship, as such:

```
TABLE person {
    id        INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    firstname VARCHAR(32),
    lastname  VARCHAR(32)
}

TABLE addresses {
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    person_id  INTEGER FOREIGN KEY ON person.id, --Reference on person-row
    street     VARCHAR(64),
    ...
}
```

The person_DO does not need to know about that, but the datamapper does, as it has to aggregate the data during loading and separate during persisting:

```
class person_DM {
    /**
     * @param  [integer] $id
     * @return [person_DO] an instance of a person or null, if no person
     *                     with that id was found.
     */
    public function findById ($id) {...}

    /**
     * @return [array of person_DO]
     */
    public function fetchAll() {...}

    /**
     * persists a person object
     * @param [person_DO] an instance of a person
     */
    public function saveOrUpdate(person_DO $person) {...}
}
```

In order to decouple the different parts even more, the DataMappers usually use the *DbTable Gateway* or a similar pattern to allow the use of different databases or similar actions. That way, I can have several databases with the same schemas, but e.g. in different organizations to build a data warehouse with the same code, only different database objects.

As a practical example, I would suggest looking at the [Quickstart Tutorial](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/learning.quickstart.html) of the Zend Framework, which does exactly what I just explained briefly.

Comment: How would a mapper handle a domain which has bilateral many to many relations? Say if that person_DO had many address_DOs or something. If you wanted to change the addresses the person has would you change that in the domain and then leave it up to the mapper to persist the new relations that the person_DO has? or would you use the mapper to change the database records which would in turn update the domain..?

Comment: "This domain model is usually a collection of data without logic."

I don't think that statement is necessarily accurate. Your domain objects should represent state + behavior (business logic). What you don't want them to do is include persistence logic.

Comment: "This domain model is usually a collection of data without logic.". That is not accurate at all. That;s an anemic model and petty poor, you domain logic SHOULD be inside your domain objects, that's simple encapsulation.

Comment: @Andrew, @AgmLauncher, What Lars is describing here with `person_DO` is a separation between the domain *entity* and the domain *logic*, which is a very common thing to do (but of course, not required).  Try not to get hung up on the terms, but rather the ideas.

Answer (score 8):

The approximate way, yes. Though I would highly recommend not to re-invent the wheel and use a sophisticated ORM like [Doctrine 2.x](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm) which implement such a pattern. You could have a look at their documentation ([Chapter 8: Working with objects](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.1/en/reference/working-with-objects.html)) to sample the interface.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good book about the topic you're interested in, You can find about data Mappers (Abstract Data Mappers) in the Persistence Framework chapter:

[Applying UML and Patterns: An Introduction to Object-Oriented Analysis and Design and the Unified Process](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130925691)