# Object interface to db gothcas?

Tags: php, database, oop

I'm recently converting some older functional programming to OOP in PHP.  The following loader function just occurred to me, but I'm suspicious there may be hidden gotchas.  Does anyone know of reasons this pattern is a bad idea?  My idea is to make this a base-class function to be inherited.

```
 public function load($objrow) {
     // ingest a db object to reset this object
     $keys = get_object_vars(self);
     foreach( $keys as $k ){
         $this->{$k} = $objrow->{$k};
     }
 }
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Better suited for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: "Thoughts?" What why? What's a base class? Is it some magical god class thing? What does this have to do with OOP?

Comment: I could be wrong, but if you are worried about DB interaction with objects, you should take a look at [domain models and mappers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988111/understanding-the-domain-object-data-mapper-pattern).  That is a real nice pattern and may get you going in the right direction.